# Pug Unbuffered Code Variable Interpolation Not Working but Buffered Code does

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to create an express app using Pug for templating. I cannot figure out why when I am using an unbuffered variable interpolation, the object is undefined but when I remove the dash it seems to work just fine (minus that it literally displays the object)

```
//index.pug

extends layout

block campground 
  - var campgrounds = '#{camps}'
    .row
      each campground in campgrounds
        div.col-md-3.col-sm-6
          div
            img(src=`${campground.image}` class='img-thumbnail')
            a(href=`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
              h4.caption.text-center #{campground.name}





//app.js

app.get('/campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const camps = await Camp.find();
        res.render('index', { camps: camps });
    } catch (ex) {
        res.status(500).send('internal error');
    }
});
```

Syntax 1:

```
- var campgrounds = '#{camps}'
```

Produces:

[image]

Syntax 2:

```
var campgrounds = '#{camps}'
```

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can:

1. Remove the row `- var campgrounds = '#{camps}'` and replace the row `each campground in campgrounds` on `each campground in camps` (see the code snippet below).
2. Or you also can replace `- var campgrounds = '#{camps}'` on `- var campgrounds = camps` (you don't need interpolation in code rows).

```js
$(function() {

    // in your code you get `camps` from DB
    // const camps = await Camp.find();
    const camps = [{name: 'Camp1'}, {name: 'Camp2'}, {name: 'Camp3'}];

    var json = {
        camps: camps
    };

    // jade compile
    // instead of your function res.render(...);
    $("#so").html(jade.compile($("#jadehi").html())(json));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/0.27.7/jade.min.js"></script>

<div id="so">SEO(please enable javascript~)</div>
<pre id="jadehi" style="display:none">
.content
  .row
    each campground in camps
      div.col-md-3.col-sm-6
        div.
          Campground: #{campground.name}
          <!-- img(src=`${campground.image}` class='img-thumbnail') -->
          <!-- a(href=`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`) -->
            <!-- h4.caption.text-center #{campground.name} -->

</pre>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works like charm. I guess I misunderstood the purpose of code interpolation. Thank you for your help.